# UPDATE with a stored procedure on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
UPDATE users 
SET field = my_sp()
```

in SQL Server 2005. Apparently I can't do this and have to use some form of EXEC. Can anyone help me out and let me know how to do this? This should be some easy rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign value you need to use sql function. it is impossible to assign value from stored procedure.
Here is [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) how to create it.

Comment: Thanks, I've converted to a scalar function. You got the acceptance mark because you gave a link to the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a scalar function that takes some parameters (or even zero) and returns what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the output of the stored procedure in a temp table, then use that temp table as the basis for your update. As an example, the code below assumes your proc returns a record set with two integers.

```
create table #t (
    ColumnA int,
    ColumnB int
)

insert into #t
    (ColumnA, ColumnB)
    exec my_sp

update u
    set field = t.ColumnB
    from users u
        inner join #t t
            on u.UserID = t.ColumnA

drop table #t
```

Comment: Clever solution, thanks, but I've already converted to a function.

Comment: @cookiecaper: That's the better way to go. I just wanted to give another alternative in case that wasn't an option for you.