# problem with update using scalar function

Tags: sql-server

i have created a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindDistrictId (@param XML)
RETURNS INT
(...)
```

which i want to use in a stored procedure like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDistinctID
AS  
    UPDATE Notices SET DistinctId = FindDistrictId(Notices.XmlContent)
    WHERE DistinctId = 0
```

I get 'FIndDistrictId is not a recognized built-in function name' when i try to do that. I thought that maybe i can't do `Set field = function()` but then i checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842679/update-with-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server-2005) and i think it should work.. any idea why it's not? The function is created for sure im my db, i checked sys.object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the schema (owner if this is SQL 2000 or earlier) of the function on the call. By default, that would be `dbo`.

```
UPDATE Notices SET DistinctId = dbo.FindDistrictId(Notices.XmlContent)
WHERE DistinctId = 0
```

Comment: I try doing that, but now the error is 'cannot find either column dbo or the user defined function or aggregate "dbo.FindDistrictID" or the name is ambigiuous'. However, this code:
declare @temp xml
set @temp = (select xmlcontent from Notices where NoticeId= 25647)
print(dbo.FindDistrictId(@temp))
seems to work ok

Comment: my mistake, seems to work fine with your modification, thank you